# The expired time of data and `keep` parameter in TDengine

Tags: sql, tdengine

I'm using TDengine database 2.1.3.0. I create a table with `keep` as 10.

I found that the data inserted 10 days ago are still in the database.

What may be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

There is another parameter called "days" with default value 10 in TDengine. TDengine stores data in one data file every 10 days, this data file will not be deleted until all the data in the data file expire.

For example:

one data file may have data from Mar 15 to Mar 25, on Mar 26th, the data of Mar 15 should be expired, but this data file also have data from Mar 16 to Mar 25, so this data file should not be deleted. The data of Mar 15 should be still in database